# Correlation and Distance biplot using autoplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggfortify, biplot

With an example provided by R (USArrests), I would like to ask if anyone can tell me what the scaling in the autoplot induces? I am familiar with a distance and correlation biplot as described in Borcard et al. (2011). The autoplot function makes the biplot nicer but I cannot find how you simply destinguish between distance and correlation type biplot using the function.

```
# Distance biplot (scaling = 1)
biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE), scale=0)
```

[image]

```
# correlation biplot (scaling =2)
biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE), pc.biplot=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
# using autoplot there are several options: 
library(ggfortify)
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), pc.biplot=TRUE, label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
# I assume this is equal to the correlation biplot
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), scale=0, label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), scale=1, label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), scale=2, label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Can I simply plot a distance (scaling = 1) using autoplot?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE), scale = 0, label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

and

```
biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE), scale = s)
```

give analogous results for 0 <= s <= 1. See `stats:::biplot.prcomp` and `ggfortify:::autoplot.prcomp` to convince yourself. In particular, both functions have (the following is from `stats:::biplot.prcomp`)

```
lam <- x$sdev[choices]
n <- NROW(scores)
lam <- lam * sqrt(n)
lam <- lam^scale
biplot.default(t(t(scores[, choices])/lam), t(t(x$rotation[, 
        choices]) * lam), ...)
```

which explains the role of `scale`. Also see `?ggbiplot` and `?autoplot.prcomp`.

Comment: @H.F.S C., does it answer your question?

Comment: Hi, 
I think I have a very similar question about how the scaling is working in the autoplot() function. Does it make any sense to set a scaling in autoplot() if you don't want to set scale = TRUE in prcomp() ?
In other words: is the "scale" from autoplot() doing the same thing as the "scale" from prcomp() ? Because it doesn't seem to do the same thing on my own data.